# Pushing a whole new project to a private Forked Project using sourcetree

Tags: git, github

I have created a clone repo on my system using SourceTree of a private GitHub project.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH431.png]

Now I want to push a whole new changed project to to the same GitHub link i.e
https://github.com/example-user/example.git.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply update the local working tree with your new project files, add and commit, and push.

That means you would replace the existing files with a new set of files, and the new commit would reflect both the deletion of the old files, and the additions of the new ones.

Comment: I am still unable to do that!

Comment: @nauman OK. What error do you have? Why simply replacing your files with new files wouldn't be correctly detected/updated by Git?

Comment: I click on push in sourcetree..it saying pushed. but it dont update on github server repository

Comment: I am committing the changes first then pushing. Pulling is also not working, although it shows successfull pulling but it dont change my local source with server source

Comment: @naumanashraf then it is best to go to the command-line interface and see what it is going on.